# Vert.x: PostgreSql result containing DateTime not getting added to JsonArray

Tags: postgresql, jodatime, vert.x

I have a sql query which returns DateTime as one of the objects. I am getting an error when it is being to added to JsonArray.

Stack Trace:

```
SEVERE: An exception occurred
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal type in JsonObject: class org.joda.time.DateTime
    at io.vertx.core.json.Json.checkAndCopy(Json.java:120)
    at io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray.add(JsonArray.java:437)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl$2.apply(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:286)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl$2.apply(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:274)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1195)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at com.github.mauricio.async.db.general.ArrayRowData.foreach(ArrayRowData.scala:22)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.rowToJsonArray(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:274)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.access$000(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:46)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl$1.apply(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:265)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl$1.apply(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:262)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1195)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at com.github.mauricio.async.db.general.MutableResultSet.foreach(MutableResultSet.scala:27)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.rowDataSeqToJsonArray(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:262)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.queryResultToResultSet(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.lambda$null$10(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:130)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.ScalaUtils$3.apply(ScalaUtils.java:81)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.ScalaUtils$3.apply(ScalaUtils.java:77)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.VertxEventLoopExecutionContext.lambda$execute$5(VertxEventLoopExecutionContext.java:70)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$18(ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I believe the error is occuring here:

```
  private List<JsonArray> rowDataSeqToJsonArray(com.github.mauricio.async.db.ResultSet set) {
    List<JsonArray> list = new ArrayList<>();
    set.foreach(new AbstractFunction1<RowData, Void>() {
      @Override
      public Void apply(RowData row) {
        list.add(rowToJsonArray(row));
        return null;
      }
    });
    return list;
  }
```

My Rowdata looks like this:

```
Some(MutableResultSet(ArrayRowData(, , hphan, 2016-04-26T00:00:00.000-07:00, 1), ArrayRowData(, , hphan, 2016-04-28T00:00:00.000-07:00, 2), ArrayRowData(BXBSVA, BLUE CROSS BLUE SHIELD VIRGINIA, null, 2016-04-26T00:00:00.000-07:00, 1)))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: The problem is probably in the rowToJsonArray() method. Either way - you can't put the DateTime object in a JsonArray.

Comment: You need to work with `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE`. And parse the result with Joda. At least this is how I'm doing it. As @Will already said `JsonArray` doesn't support other types than listed [here](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/3.2.1/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/json/Json.java#L84).

Answer (score 0):

This should work with the upcoming release 3.3. However note that the asynchronous client is marked as technology preview so there are rough edges.

Having that said if you need more features that I'd suggest to use the jdbc client instead. While not so high performance it is feature complete.